# Implementing a tree view in seam / JSF using Richfaces or jsTree

Tags: jsf, treeview, tree, seam, richfaces

I am using seam with EJB3 + JSF and I would like to add a tree view component to the UI.  The tree view must allow sorting of the nodes (preferably drag and drop) and must allow selection of leaf nodes.

The options I have looked at are:

- [RichFaces Tree](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tree.jsf)
- jsTree

Is there a major benefit to one option over the other?

If I use jsTree, what is the best way to connect to my data in EJB3?  Should I use RESTEasy , Java script Remoting, or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Richfaces tree as you are already using JSF becuase in this way everything is pretty much integrated and you wouldnt have to "wire" all the requirements manually.

The major benefit with richfaces is that everything is already there so the development time is shorter.

Comment: I was able to get a tree implementation working very quickly.